# Print V-Pattern Formed by Array Elements using C++

Tags: c++, arrays

How to print the array elements that forms a v-pattern using C++?

The program should ask the user to input number of columns, number of rows, and what characters to be stored. Then outputs the array elements that forms a v-pattern. Constraints in the number of columns should always be odd.

Sample input:

Enter number of rows: 3

Enter number of columns: 3

Enter characters:

a b c

d e f

g h i

Sample output:
a e c

Another example:

Enter number of rows: 3

Enter number of columns: 5

Enter characters:

a b c t z

d e f w x

g h i v y

Sample output:
a e i w z

Comment: Why not d-h-f ?

Comment: @Cherkesgiller only the pattern that starts from the top

Comment: Is there any constraint on "V" form , for ex: width of "v" or etc

Comment: @Cherkesgiller depends of the rows and column input by the user. Let's say for example:

The user input in rows is 4, also 5 in column, and the characters input are:

a b c z t

d e f x u

g h i y v

j k l w s

then the output should be a e i c t

Comment: @SidjeyKun I don't believe there's an array needed to solve that.

Comment: Did you want to say a e i x t ?

Comment: @Cherkesgiller ohh yah, a e i x t, thanks for correction

Comment: Can you give an example when rows and colums both have 4 elements?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ well, it's part of my online resources in c++ practice, i don't know how to answer it though so i can't have any progress

Comment: @Cherkesgiller the program doesn't receive 4x4 because the array will not form v-patter

Comment: @SidjeyKun work something out with pencil and paper 1st.

Comment: Then please ask questions detally in here.

Comment: @Cherkesgiller another constraints is that, the column should only have odd numbers

Comment: @Cherkesgiller Sorry, it's my first time posting a question. Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Nice puzzle with indices.

If you look at your matrix and follow the V for output, then the first observation is that always a character from the next column will be used.

So, if we iterate over the indices in the matrix, then we start with a column value of 0 and always add 1.

For the row it is a little bit more difficult. We go one row down, until we are column wise in the middle of the matrix. Then we go up again.

So, we start with row 0. Then we add a delta. In the beginning 1. If we are in the middle (currentColumn is greater than numberOfColumns/2) then we modify the delta value to -1. Then, by still adding the delta to the row, the row will now get smaller again. And with that we move up in the matrix.

Example for row/column indices in a 3x5 matrix:

```
0/0              0/4      
    1/1     1/3
        2/2
```

A potential implementation could look like the below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() { 

    // Here we will store the matrix size
    int numberOfRows{};
    int numberOfColumns{};

    // Get number of rows and number of columns. Check for correct input
    std::cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
    if ((std::cin >> numberOfRows) and (numberOfRows > 0)) {

        std::cout << "Enter number of columns (odd): ";
        if ((std::cin >> numberOfColumns) and (numberOfColumns > 0) and (numberOfColumns % 2)) {

            // Define Matrix
            std::vector<std::vector<char>> matrix(numberOfRows, std::vector<char>(numberOfColumns, {}));

            // Get the matrix values
            for (std::vector<char>& row : matrix)
                for (char& col : row) std::cin >> col;

            // Now output the result:
            std::cout << "\n\nSample output: ";

            // We will move the rows up and down, depending on the column
            int row{};
            int rowDelta{ 1 };

            for (int col{}; col < numberOfColumns; ++col) {

                // Show next character
                std::cout << matrix[row][col] << ' ';
                
                // If we are over the middle
                if (col >= (numberOfColumns/2))

                    // Then go up again
                    rowDelta = -1;

                // Change row
                row += rowDelta;
            }
        }
        else
            std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Invalid Input for columns\n";
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Invalid Input for rows\n";
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation right there, thanks for the very detailed algorithm. It's been a big help for me!